# How does Left Join / IS NULL eliminate records which are there in one table and not in the other?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, isnull

I am having a tough time to understand why does `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` eliminate records which are there in one table and not in the other.
Here is an example

```
SELECT  l.id, l.value
FROM    t_left l
LEFT JOIN t_right r
ON      r.value = l.value
WHERE   r.value IS NULL
```

Why should `r.value = NULL` eliminate records ? I am not understanding . I know I am missing something very basic but at present I cant figure out even that basic one. I would appreciate if someone explains it to me in detail .

I want a very basic explanation.

Comment: in your example, the result would be EVERY record from t_left, as well as every matching record from t_right.  where there is no match, NULL values are given instead of values from t_right

Comment: Understand how a LEFT JOIN works and the rest will make sense. Run the query without the WHERE statement and imagine applying it.

Comment: Just run this: `SELECT * FROM t_left l LEFT JOIN t_right r ON r.value = l.value`. Now it should be obvious!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be explained with the following

```
mysql> select * from table1 ;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 |   10 |
|    2 |   30 |
|    3 |   40 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2 ;
+------+------+
| id   | t1id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here `table1.id <-> table2.t1id`

Now when we do a `left join` with the joining key and if the left table is table1 then it will get all the data from table1 and in non-matching record on table2 will be set to null

```
mysql> select t1.* , t2.t1id from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.t1id = t1.id ;
+------+------+------+
| id   | val  | t1id |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |   10 |    1 |
|    2 |   30 |    2 |
|    3 |   40 | NULL |
+------+------+------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See that table1.id = 3 does not have a value in table2 so its set as null
When you apply the where condition it will do further filtering

```
mysql> select t1.* , t2.t1id from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.t1id = t1.id where t2.t1id is null;
+------+------+------+
| id   | val  | t1id |
+------+------+------+
|    3 |   40 | NULL |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume r-table is employees, and r_table is computers. Some employees don't have computers. Some computers are not assigned to anyone yet.

1. Inner join:

   ```
   SELECT  l.*, r.*
   FROM    employees l
   JOIN computers r
   ON      r.id = l.comp_id
   ```

   gives you the list of all employees who HAVE a computer, and the info about computer assigned for each of them. The employees without a computer will NOT appear on this list.
2. Left join:

   ```
   SELECT  l.*, r.*
   FROM    employees l
   LEFT JOIN computers r
   ON      r.id = l.comp_id
   ```

   gives you the list of ALL employees. The employees with computer will show the computer info. The employees without computers will appear with NULLs instead of computer info.
3. Finally

   ```
   SELECT  l.*, r.*
   FROM    employees l
   LEFT JOIN computers r
   ON      r.id = l.comp_id
   WHERE   r.id IS NULL
   ```

   Left join with the WHERE clause will start with the same list as the left join **(2)**, but then it will keep only those employees that do not have corresponding information in the computer table, that is, employees without the computers.

   I this case, selecting anything from the `r` table will be just nulls, so you can leave those fields out and select only stuff from the `l` table:

   ```
   SELECT  l.*
   FROM ...
   ```

Try this sequence of selects and observe the output. Each next step builds on the previous one.

Please let me know if this explanation is understandable, or you'd like me to elaborate some more.

EDITED TO ADD:
Here's sample code to create the two tables used above:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(20),
   comp_id INT);

INSERT INTO employees (id, name, comp_id) VALUES (1, 'Becky', 1);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, comp_id) VALUES (2, 'Anne', 7);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, comp_id) VALUES (3, 'John', 3);
INSERT INTO employees (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Bob');

CREATE TABLE computers
(  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   os VARCHAR(20) );

INSERT INTO computers (id, os) VALUES (1,'Windows 7');
INSERT INTO computers (id, os) VALUES (2,'Windows XP');
INSERT INTO computers (id, os) VALUES (3,'Unix');
INSERT INTO computers (id, os) VALUES (4,'Windows 7');
```

There are 4 employees. Becky and John have computers. Anne and Bob do not have a computer. (Anne, has a comp_id 7, which doesn't correspond to any row in computers table - so, she doesn't really have a computer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.v = b.v ... WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

it's super simple logic:

- select from table "a"
- join table "b" (if matching rows exists - ON a.v=b.v otherwise use NULL's as values)
- WHERE condition: if something is missing (b.id IS NULL) = OK.

Comment: this doesn't explain why there are nulls in the first place

Comment: @pala_ how so? you select from A

Comment: yes, but from the question it seems some of the problem is understanding that nulls come from rows that dont match, because its a left join - as opposed to inner joining

Comment: This statement is flat wrong  "join table "b" (if matching rows exists - ON a.v=b.v)".  You are describing an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

the left returns all the row from the left table

ON  r.value = l.value
if there is no r.value for a l.value then the r is empty
r.value is null will be true

Answer (score 1):

in your example, the result would be EVERY record from `t_left`, as well as every matching record from `t_right` where they both have the same `value`. where there is no match, `NULL` values are given instead of values from `t_right`. `where r.value is null` simply eliminates the rows that did match, by detecting those `null` values.

essentially saying 'give me the rows from `t_left` that DONT match rows in `t_right`

a `right join` performs the reverse order of the `left join`.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. When you use an `INNER JOIN`, the result only contains rows that match between the two tables (based on the `ON` condition).

But when you use a `LEFT JOIN`, you also get rows in the result for all rows in the first table that *don't* have a match in the second table. In these cases, all the result columns from the second table are filled with `NULL` as a placeholder.

The `WHERE r.value IS NULL` test then matches these rows. So the final result only contains the rows with no match.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN takes the values on the left and tries to match the table on the left by the column specified on ON if it doesn't find a match then it interprets the right table's columns as NULL. hence only those that can't find a match on the right table will be selected by IS NULL operator

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a left join states that all records from the left table will be include, and only those from the right that match.

So lets say you have a `red`, `blue` and `green` sock in your drawer, and your friend only a `red`, `yellow` and `blue`, a left join from your drawer to your friends would return all the socks from your drawer (`red`, `blue` and `green`) and only matching ones from your friends (`red` and `blue`).

Now the IS NULL part says that you want to see all socks from your drawer, where there are not matching pair partners in your friends drawer, so from all your socks the only one with a missing pair is the `green` sock.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence:

```
SELECT  l.id, l.value
FROM    t_left l
LEFT JOIN t_right r
ON      r.value = l.value
```

will have all the elements from `t_left` table joined to all elements from `t_right` table. As you probably will now, in an `INNER JOIN` only rows which matches both tables will be shown, so `t_left` **could have less rows** than all the possible rows. In a `LEFT JOIN`, you have ALL THE ROWS from `t_left` table plus the matched rows from `t_right` (if they can be joined). So, what happens with rows in t_left that not matches any t_right row? All the fields from t_right table that would be supposed to contain data will be filled with NULL values. So, if you only select `NULL` values from right table, you'll find all the values from the `t_left` table that has no match on the right one, XD

Answer (score 1):

`Left join` gives all records from left table. If the any key present in left table is missing in right table all right table column will be null, but all the left table values will be present.

It is the basic difference between inner join and left / right join.

Thus when you do 'r.value = null` you get those records from left where there is no matching key in right table.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple Left join funda.....
following Query get all the record from left table and matched record From Right table if it doesn't match than it will return **NUll** value. at The end you filter data by using where condition  which return values that are **in Left table but not in right table**

```
 SELECT  l.id, l.value
    FROM    t_left l
    LEFT JOIN t_right r
    ON      r.value = l.value
    WHERE   r.value IS NULL
```